# After sending the form, the boxes are shown in red but the form is sent. this is the code that I have

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the code that i have, after completing the form and pressing the submit button, the form is sent correctly but the fields turn red as if they are not completed. I would like to know what is wrong or what I have to change in this code. I found several options on the internet but I can not fix the problem.

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  var form = $('.contact__form'),
    message = $('.contact__msg'),
    form_data;

  // Success function
  function done_func(response) {
    message.fadeIn().removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
    message.text(response);
    setTimeout(function() {
      message.fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
    form.find('input:not([type="submit"]), textarea').val('');
  }

  // fail function
  function fail_func(data) {
    message.fadeIn().removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-success');
    message.text(data.responseText);
    setTimeout(function() {
      message.fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
  }

  form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form_data
      })
      .done(done_func)
      .fail(fail_func);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* ------- */


/* CONTACT */


/* ------- */

#contact {
  background: #1d1e22;
  padding: 6em 1em 4em;
}

.contact {
  background: #1d1e22;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.contact h3 {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}


/* ---- */


/* FORM */


/* ---- */

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5A5A5A;
  color: #fff;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #EAEAEA;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.contact form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.contact form label {
  display: block;
}

.contact form p {
  margin: 0;
}

.contact form .full {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.contact form button,
.contact form input,
.contact form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.contact form textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5A5A5A;
  color: #fff;
}

.contact form button {
  background: #BB4F51;
  border: 0;
  color: #e4e4e4;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.contact form button:hover,
.contact form button:focus {
  background: #8F3D3F;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: 0;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CONTACT FORM -->
<div class="contact">
  <form class="contact__form" method="post" action="mail.php">
    <p>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nume" required data-error="Introduceți numele.">

    </p>

    <p>

      <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Telefon" required data-error="Introduceți numarul de telefon.">

    </p>


    <p>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail (Correo Electronico)" required data-error="Introduceți un e-mail.">
    </p>

    <p>

      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Reclamatie / Informatii" required data-error="Introduceți un subiect.">
    </p>

    <p class="full">
      <textarea name="message" rows="5" id="msg" placeholder="Mesaj / Reclamatie" required data-error="Scrieți un mesaj."></textarea>
    </p>

    <p class="full">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Trimite</button>
    </p>


    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="alert alert-success contact__msg" style="display: none" role="alert">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Mesajul dumneavostră a fost trimis cu succes.<br />
      </div>
    </div>


  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP?

Comment: i use php as well, but i don't kmow how to text it here

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks I think we need the `mail.php` to help, that is where the validation is being done, right?

Comment: Is your PHP code relevant to the issue? If yes, add that code. If no, then it shouldn't be tagged. Only add relevant tags.

Comment: i will try to add it

Comment: my form use a php file, but i don't know how to publish here in the question :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When I fill out the form and click submit, I can see the ajax request in the dev tools but the fields do not turn red in any way.

Comment: i think  it not work without the php file

Comment: @ChrisG - The CSS is missing the alert-error and alert-success classes.

Comment: are you talking about these? because i have them in the php file.                             if ($success) {
            # Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong, we couldn't send your message.";
        }

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the attribute "required" in form input elements, and you're setting value as ' ' (an empty value but not null) after success operation of the ajax POST by the function done_func(), this causes the fields becoming red like. 
Solution is try "resetting" fields instead of setting ' ' value.

Eg: [input type="reset" id="x"...] then trigger it via jQuery.

Comment: DG_ thank you very much for your help, forgive me for my bad english

Comment: If that solves your problem, please mark my answer as accepted. This will help for future problem facers.